# WorkFlow email to summarize a days worth of infromation

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a basic Workflow that emails an accounts department when a new payment is made. A simple list governs all of this.
Instead of sending one email for each list entry I would like to send one email at the end of the day summarising all payments. How can I achieve this in SPD2010?
Many Thanks

Comment: What about Timer Job? At the end of the day, the Job runs, reads the list and sends emails ;)

Comment: Sounds good, how does this work, can it be done in SPD2010??

Answer (score 1):

Rather than developing a workflow, can you try out the Alert/ Notification options in which we can configure email frequency.

Comment: Thanks Joy, issue with alerts is that they do not contain the metadata and perform calculations such as calculate the price fields within the list

Comment: Yes, I agree that. Go for a Timer Job. You can schedule it to run based on your schedule. You can read the list data from the Timer Job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer Job.

A Timer Job is a periodically executed task inside SharePoint Server. It provides us a task execution environment.

Here you can find a tutorial on [Timer Job](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403323/SharePoint-Create-Custom-Timer-Jobs)

Comment: Thanks, I do not have Visual Studio though. Is there a way to do this without?

Comment: You can use some workarounds (see points 4 and 5): https://www.definitivelogic.com/blog/timer-job-workaround